# Are 90 minutes enough for London Luton inbound connection?

Tags: short-connections, easyjet, wizz-air, self-transfer, luton

Inbound flight Wizzair from SOF scheduled to arrive at 17:20. Outbound flight Easyjet to GLA scheduled to depart at 18:55.

Is this a risky connection if happening on Saturday 13th January 2024, and the passenger travels light?
The passenger can use a biometric passport at the egates if faster.

Comment: I assume different two flight on different tickets? There are around 6 connections between Luton and Glasgow, so possibly your connection is the last one). For me the answer depends a lot on your risk preferences ( + how much you like travel adventures) (Note: last minute hotel booking near airport are often too expensive), and Luton is not well served by public transports (but you may get busses to Cambridge or Ely, and there you can go Norths). I would do it (for some of my travels),

Comment: Luton is a point-to-point airport AFAIK, one Terminal and no airside transit. Allowing for the 30 minute gate closure for your on bound flight you have an hour to clear Immigration then go back through security to get to your gate. Do-able providing your inbound flight isn’t delayed. Depends on your risk appetite.

Comment: I suppose "travels light" means no hold luggage, but if there is hold luggage this is definitely impossible. Same if there is any other reason to need to go to a check-in desk (can't do online/mobile check-in for instance).

Comment: I flew WizzAir from Sofia to Luton once a year ago (or maybe 2 at this point); passport control took _forever_ because the egates were non-functional. Luckily I was one of only 4 non-EU/UK passport holders so got through much faster than the poor shmucks with the "better" passports.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> is this a risky connection?

Yes.

Every self transfer is risky and a 90 minute one is very risky. Sure, if all things go perfect, you have a good chance of making it. But flights can be (and often are) delayed, security lines can be long, immigration officers can be on dinner break, etc.

Assuming that you are flying with WhizzAir from Sofia: take a look at this: https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-65228868

The main problem with a self connection are the consequences of missing it: you are a no show for your second ticket and you may have to buy a brand-new same day ticket on the spot. Given the time of day, you may have to pony up for a hotel as well. That can get very expensive.

Comment: Since the second flight is with easyJet, a ticket for a missed flight can be “rescued” within a two-hour window [for £110](https://www.easyjet.com/en/terms-and-conditions/fees), so at least there’s a known limit for how much the new ticket should cost. (If it’s less than £110, buy a new ticket; otherwise, rescue the previous one.) The 18:55 flight to GLA is the last of the day (on easyJet), so a hotel stay would indeed probably be involved.